# Image Uploader No Response in Database mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, upload

I modify codes provided by people and I face a problem that, it runs very well and fine in Android. but..it does not give any response nor the database.. rows are still remain the same  after the function.. What mistake had i done? Thanks!

Android codes goes here:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Uri currImageURI;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button gallery_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gallerybtn);
    gallery_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            //to open up a gallery browser
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture.."),1);          

        }

    });

    Button upload_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadbtn);
    upload_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){

            new HttpUploader().execute(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));       

        }

    });

}   

// To handle when an image is selected from the browser
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // currImageURI is the global variable I’m using to hold the content:
            currImageURI = data.getData();

            EditText tv_path = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
            tv_path.setText(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));

        }

    }
}

//Convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
public String getRealPathFromURI( Uri contentUri) {
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    android.database.Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri,
            proj,     // Which columns to return
            null,     // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
            null,     // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
            null);     // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String c = cursor.getString(column_index); 
    return c;
}

public class HttpUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image.. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

     protected String doInBackground(String... path) {

         String outPut = null;

         for (String sdPath : path) {

             Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdPath);
             ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

             //Resize the image
             double width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
             double height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
             double ratio = 400/width;
             int newheight = (int)(ratio*height);

             System.out.println("———-width" + width);
             System.out.println("———-height" + height);

             bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, 400, newheight, true);

             //Here you can define .PNG as well
             bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, bao);
             byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
             String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

             String id = "99";
             ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", sdPath));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

             try {
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/upload.php");
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();                

                 // print responce
                 outPut = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                 Log.i("GET RESPONSE—-", outPut);

                 //is = entity.getContent();
                 Log.e("log_tag ******", "good connection");

                 bitmapOrg.recycle();

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e("log_tag ******", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
             }
         }
         return outPut;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
 }
}
```

Logcat shows this only : log_tag ******", "good connection

PHP file goes here:

```
<?php
 include "db_connection.php";

if (isset($base)) {
    $base = $_REQUEST["image"];
    $filepath = $_REQUEST["path"];
    $id = $_REQUEST["id"];

    $image_name = "/image/".$filepath;

    // base64 encoded utf-8 string
    $binary = base64_decode($base);

    // binary, utf-8 bytes

    header("Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8");

    $file = fopen($image_name, "wb");

    fwrite($file, $binary);

    fclose($file);

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE restaurants SET image = '$image_name' WHERE ID = '$id'");

    if(mysql_affected_rows > 0){
        echo json_encode("success!");
    }else{
        echo json_encode("failed!");
    }

} else {
       echo json_encode("missing required attribute!"); 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace this code part :

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE restaurants SET image = '$image_name' WHERE ID = '$id'");

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() <> 0){
    echo json_encode("success!");
}else{
    echo json_encode("failed!");
}
```

Comment: it still remains the same >.< but how should i check whether it is success / failed?  
i should Log.e("",??); or something in Android?

Comment: $result = mysql_query(); ex

Comment: "UPDATE restaurants SET image = '$image_name' WHERE ID = '$id'" part put on mysql_query();

Comment: u mean? the line of code is incorrect?

Comment: yes "UPDATE restaurants SET image = '$image_name' WHERE ID = '$id'" part put on this function mysql_query();

Comment: had made changes. but. no clue.. =( remains the same... going smooth and displaying good connection.. in that log